# Wrong implementation of Karatsuba Multiplication

Tags: python, karatsuba

How can I implement the implementation of Karatsuba Multiplication?
Inputs are given in a string.

### This is my code

```
def multiply(x,y):
    x_len = len(x) 
    y_len = len(y)
    lenn= max(x_len,y_len) 
    len2=lenn//2
    
    if x_len < 3 or y_len <3:
        return int(x)*int(y)
    
    else:
        a= x[ : len2]
        b= x[ len2 : ]
        c= y[ : len2]    
        d= y[ len2 : ]

        S1 = multiply(a,c)
        S2 = multiply(b,d)
        S3 = multiply(str(int(a)+int(b)) , str(int(c)+int(d)))
        S4 = str(S3 - S2 - S1)

        X1= S1 * 10**(lenn)
        X2 = S3 * 10**(len2)
        X3 = S2

        return X1+X2+X3
```

Comment: What is wrong about your implementation?

Comment: Please add more information...

Comment: What was the point in computing `S4`?  You never use it anywhere...

Comment: Thank you Jasonharper. Really glad you guys helped :)